# Zimbra Briefcase upload size limit not clear

Tags: postfix-mta, zimbra

I wanted to upload a file in my Zimbra briefcase and got the message that the size is too large (> 36MB).

I search how to increase this limit and got the following results in which I don't see the 36MB limit, can sb explain this ?

```
*) /opt/zimbra/postfix/conf/main.cf | grep message_size_limit
message_size_limit = 51200000
*) postconf | grep message_size_limit
message_size_limit = 51200000
*) zmprov gcf zimbraMtaMaxMessageSize
zimbraMtaMaxMessageSize: 51200000
*) zmprov gcf zimbraFileUploadMaxSize
zimbraFileUploadMaxSize: 51200000
*) zmprov gcf zimbraMailContentMaxSize
zimbraMailContentMaxSize: 10240000
*) zmprov gacf | grep zimbraMtaMaxMessageSize
zimbraMtaMaxMessageSize: 51200000
*) zmprov gacf | grep zimbraFileUploadMaxSize
zimbraFileUploadMaxSize: 51200000
zimbraFileUploadMaxSizePerFile: 2147483648
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please read carefully, only 1 question, where does the 36MB limit come form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You setup a limit of 50MB ( 51200000 ) but mime encoding consumes additional space (137%), so the limitation is 50 / 1,37 = 36MB

Have a look to this doc

https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Configuring_maxmessagesize